Why am I getting operation not permitted with Homebrew?
I'm trying to install packages with Homebrew on a Mac M3 Sequoia but a lot of them don't work.
Here, I'm trying to install mysql-client@8.4 but I've the following error :
/usr/bin/env tar --extract --no-same-owner --file /Users/kenan/Library/Caches/Homebrew/downloads/05c90a11ec4eaa6c29d81f335666fac0d29998c4d47a5f9754da1d4830e4cdc8--mysql-8.4.2.tar.gz --directory /private/tmp/homebrew-unpack20241014-80246-ct5fv1
/usr/bin/env cp -al /private/tmp/homebrew-unpack20241014-80246-ct5fv1/mysql-8.4.2 /private/tmp/mysql-clientA8.4-20241014-80246-sx0s0x
==> Temporary files retained at:
/private/tmp/mysql-clientA8.4-20241014-80246-sx0s0x
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted @ dir_s_mkdir - /System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql-client@8.4

Here is my brew config if needed :
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 4.4.1
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: 70672606c6ac07a5e8f75abeda7b8736e8285dbe
Last commit: 11 hours ago
Core tap JSON: 14 Oct 18:01 UTC
Core cask tap JSON: 14 Oct 18:01 UTC
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY: /System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew/Cellar
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 8
HOMEBREW_NO_ENV_HINTS: set
Homebrew Ruby: 3.3.5 => /opt/homebrew/Library/Homebrew/vendor/portable-ruby/3.3.5/bin/ruby
CPU: octa-core 64-bit arm_ibiza
Clang: 16.0.0 build 1600
Git: 2.39.5 => /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/git
Curl: 8.7.1 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 15.0.1-arm64
CLT: 16.0.0.0.1.1724870825
Xcode: 16.0
Rosetta 2: false

And the brew doctor output :
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry or file an issue; just ignore this. Thanks!

Warning: Unbrewed dylibs were found in /usr/local/lib.
If you didn't put them there on purpose they could cause problems when
building Homebrew formulae and may need to be deleted.

Unexpected dylibs:
  /usr/local/lib/libhidapi.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.9.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libusb-1.0.dylib
  /usr/local/lib/libzbar.dylib

Warning: Your Homebrew's prefix is not /opt/homebrew.

Many of Homebrew's bottles (binary packages) can only be used with the default prefix.
Consider uninstalling Homebrew and reinstalling into the default prefix.
It is expected behaviour that some formulae will fail to build in this unsupported configuration.
It is expected behaviour that Homebrew will be buggy and slow.
Do not create any issues about this on Homebrew's GitHub repositories.
Do not create any issues even if you think this message is unrelated.
Any opened issues will be immediately closed without response.
Do not ask for help from Homebrew or its maintainers on social media.
You may ask for help in Homebrew's discussions but are unlikely to receive a response.
Try to figure out the problem yourself and submit a fix as a pull request.
We will review it but may or may not accept it.


Did you migrate your Homebrew environment from an Intel-based Mac? Homebrew uses a different default path prefix on Intel Macs vs. Apple Silicon. I see it complaining about your path prefix, so I wonder if that might have something to do with it.

I don't migrate brew, it's my first time on Mac
How can I correct this ? Tried this but didn't worked
❯ brew config | grep PREFIX
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew
❯ export HOMEBREW_PREFIX=/opt/homebrew
❯ brew config | grep PREFIX
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /System/Volumes/Data/opt/homebrew


For all the latest macOS versions, open system settings. In privacy window, provide Full Disk Access to terminal app where you are running the commands. After updating the settings, the above error should be resolved.
If the problem happens again, try to remove /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/sbin as there might be existing symlinks to this directory.
